# is there a proper substitute for equalsIgnoreCase in Typescript?

Tags: java, typescript

I want to build a Java console app in Typescript, but I need to correct for equalsIgnoreCase in Typescript. My Java code is this:

```
private boolean isRootNote(String [] scale, String note)
{
    return note.equalsIgnoreCase(scale[0]);
}

private boolean isNoteInScale(String [] scale, String note)
{
    boolean isIn = false;
    for (String n : scale)
    {
        isIn = n.equalsIgnoreCase(note);
        if (isIn)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return isIn;

}
```

My Typescript code is this:

```
isRootNote(scale:string[], note:string):boolean
{
    return note.equalsIgnoreCase(scale[0]);
}

isNoteInScale(scale:string[], note:string):boolean
{
    let isIn:boolean = false;
    for (let n of scale)
    {
        isIn = n.equalsIgnoreCase(note);
        if (isIn)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return isIn;

}
```

The error is: Property 'equalsIgnoreCase' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
If I change my scale:string[] to scale:any[] and note:string to note:any, this error goes away, but is this good practice?

Comment: Does it actually work with those changes? I'd expect it not to, since there is no `equalsIgnoreCase`on strings in JavaScript. Unless you added that functionality to the prototype?

Comment: This is really a JavaScript question; TypeScript doesn't provide additional runtime functionality, it's adds a static type system to JavaScript and does some downleveling to target older JS runtimes, but it's still just JavaScript.

Comment: to correct myself, the red line went away, sorry. The top example/portion of code is just java from my console app in Eclipse.

Comment: The error goes away because `any` is not type checked. Try running it.